# Is there any way to force apps like Edge to run under the lock screen in Windows 10 mobile?

Tags: lock-screen, streaming

I would love to be able to leave a website streaming audio (SoundCloud or BBC iPlayer radio for instance) under the lock screen whilst I work, cycle etc.

Unfortunately, Edge will only continue playing for a short while before halting the process. Obviously some apps will continue to run under the lock screen, so I'm wondering if there is a registry key somewhere I can tweak for the apps I want to allow to run?

Not only would this prevent unwanted touch inputs, it will save battery too. 
At the moment, the best I can do is pull down the action centre, which covers the screen with mostly black, which on my Lumia 950 OLED screen, is not using battery.

It would be very useful to be able to do the same with the voice recorder too..